# How to export ANdroidStudio Project into another AndroidStudio?

Tags: import, export, android-studio

I want to export my AndroidStudio Project onto my laptop where I have also the program AndroidStudio...
how do I export my Project with all files and settings and import it without problems onto my laptop into AndroidStudio? Is that possible?

Comment: Copy-paste project folder should be fine. Did you try that?

Comment: yes that works lol :) I thought there is some more elegant method haha ;)

Comment: Just for the future, when you use github, you can easily push your project online and pull it back from any computer where you have git or android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Go to......

File->New->Import project
Then Chose your project folder and press OK .
If you have related SDk platform downloaded then your project will work well, otherwise you have to download SDK platform related to your project.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this, just choose whichever method works for you.

1. Close Android Studio, navigate to the project folder, zip it up and move it via email, usb key, dropbox/cloud storage or whatever you prefer. Then in Android Studio on the new system choose "Open an existing Android Studio Project".
2. Build the project on the USB (or in a folder that is automatically sync'd between hardware and cloud storage service) and work on it directly on the stick/in the folder so it is in one place and always up to date (unless you lose the USB stick or internet goes out).
3. (My preferred method) Use GitHub - for several reasons

   - it's cloud storage that is easily accessed anywhere you have an internet connection, especially from within Android Studio, and when you're making regular commits and pushes to GitHub you don't have to bother with zipping, making sure you have the right version, etc...
   - you can branch your main project to implement new features, play around with ideas, fix bugs, etc.. without compromising the integrity of the existing project while you experiment. When you're finished and you like what you've done, you can easily merge it into the master and move forward without a hitch.
   - if you make use of frequent commits, it helps you effortlessly document all of your changes, new features and fixes. Plus if you break something you can easily revert to the previous commit and start over without losing hours/days of work.
   - you can easily clone your project directly into Android Studio on system you're currently on, complete with all the changes you just committed on the other system and keep going without breaking your flow
   - you don't have to deal with finding and zipping the correct folder/version, hunting down that USB stick you *just* had, or  emailing, downloading, or trying to remember where you saved the project on *this* system.
   - if you do lose internet, you can still work on the project and do your commits offline,then push it to GitHub when your net comes back up
   - finally, if you want someone else's input on what you've done or potential employers want to see your work just send them to your repo

Answer (score 0):

First get the backup of which project you want. and open another android studio and select file icon to open a project or File->open project->select your project location